# AddTrust external ca root is expired

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

We are running healthchecks scripts from our aws servers, these health check scripts call apis written in various langauages and based on result decides whether applications are running fine or not, from 30 May 2020, My healthchecks are failing stating ssl certificate expired. One of the possible reason would be https://www.ssl.com/faqs/i-noticed-that-the-addtrust-external-ca-root-is-expiring-soon-will-i-be-affected/can anyone suggest what action I need to take. We are running amazon linux2 os.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tool against your server: https://whatsmychaincert.com/

If you have [the expired root certificate](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020), your most likely solution will be to change your bundle of intermediate and root certificates to simply OMIT the expired root.

Comment: I am new to this certificate area, Can you help me with step by step guide, currently as a workaround I have blacklisted AddTrust External Root from the client machine that is AWS Linux. Is there a way to get out of this from by making the change in less number of instances at server side, by not making changes at client side.